# Why is "Apple Arcade" practically never mentioned/discussed in this StackExchange community?

Tags: discussion

I've often read on popular tech blogs how family friendly and consumer friendly (no rip-offs and hidden costs) "Apple Arcade" is. Yet there are virtually no questions and answers about "Apple Arcade" here. Also no tag for "Apple Arcade".

Why? Is this platform/ecosystem irrelevant to gamers? Or only relevant for very young gamers (they are too young to participate in StackExchange)?

Comment: Just to clear this part up - tags only exist if at least _one_ corresponding question exists.  I believe even if there once was an Apple Arcade tagged question that got deleted, the tag would also get purged out by [an automated process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/342074).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't have a policy against questions about Apple Arcade, they just don't get asked here.  While we do allow questions about mobile games in general, this community has really coalesced around PC and console gaming.  I would also suspect that most users here are Android users and not iPhone users.  Having said that, the number of [android](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) questions is on the same order of magnitude as [ios](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) questions, so questions are getting asked.

Questions specifically about Apple Arcade are probably just too niche, and wouldn't be applicable to questions about individual games.  It should only be used if it's a question about how to do something or how something works in Apple Arcade, much like we use platform tags ([steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam), [xbox-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-one), etc.).

Comment: Also on Ask Different alsmost no questions https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=Arcade - why?

Comment: @Sybil You'd have to ask users that are more active in that SE, but I suspect Apple Arcade is simply not as popular.  As for this community, questions that are not explicitly about a specific game or series tend to be uncommon.  As an example, [tag:stadia] only has 2 questions and launched around the same time as Apple Arcade.

Comment: For what it's worth, there do appear to some questions for games in [apple arcade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q="apple+arcade"), there just isn't a tag for `apple-arcade`

Comment: @Wondercricket I would argue (having just looked at the search results) that they should be tagged with ios if they even need an additional tag.

Comment: The second part is a huge factor into why the apple-arcade tag is non-existant, IMO. Pretty rare that a question has the platform as a tag. The tag is usually more the game itself. The platform is only there if its about the platform itself, or if a thing is known to be on that platform only. Both being rare.